# How to start at the bottom of scroll on load of datatable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am creating a datatable wherein I need to start from the bottom of the scroll. How do I do this? I tried to do the solutions listed here in stackoverflow but it doesn't work for me.

```
//1.
var scrollBody = $(conversationData.table().node()).parent();
scrollBody.scrollTop(scrollBody.get(0).scrollHeight);

//2. 
conversationData.parent().scrollTop(9999);
// Solution number 2 returns this error:
// Uncaught TypeError: conversationData.parent is not a function

//3.
 $('.dataTables_scroll').scrollTop($('.dataTables_scroll').get(0).scrollHeight);
//OR
 $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop($('.dataTables_scrollBody').get(0).scrollHeight);

OR

$('#conversationsDT .dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop($('#conversationsDT .dataTables_scrollBody').get(0).scrollHeight);
//I tried this to be specific of what table to select
//This returns an error:
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined
```

I've tried this and some other codes but it doesn't work. See below for my code.

*Is it possible that this happens because I have 2 datatables in 1 page? But still it doesn't work with the other datatable too.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="openConvoModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="toolbar">
                </div>
                <div class="fresh-datatables">
                    <table id="conversationsDT" class="table table-no-bordered table-hover display" cellspacing="0" width="101%">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>CONVERSATION</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var conversationData = $('#conversationsDT').DataTable({
                "ordering": false,
                "bInfo" : false,
                "responsive": true,
                "processing": true,
                "bPaginate": false, 
                "scrollY": $(window).height()/1.5,
                "scrollX": false,
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "bDeferRender": true,
                "ajax": "",
                "aoColumns": [
                    {"mData": "sender",
                        "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                            var message = "";
                            if (oData.typeOfMessage === "SENT") {
                                message = message.concat("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'></div><div class='col-md-6'><span class = 'sentMessage'>");
                                message = message.concat("<p class='sentContent'>"+oData.content+"</p>");
                                if (oData.isAssignedToTicket === null) {
                                    message = message.concat("<p>NOT ASSIGNED</p>");
                                } else {
                                    message = message.concat("<a class='linkColor' href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cnr/viewEditTicket?ticketNumber=" + oData.isAssignedToTicket + "'>" + oData.isAssignedToTicket + "</a>");
                                }
                                message = message.concat("</span>");
                                message = message.concat("</div>");
                            }else{
                                message = message.concat("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-6'><p class = 'rcvMessage'>");
                                message = message.concat("<span class='sentContent'>"+oData.content+"</p>");
                                if (oData.isAssignedToTicket === null) {
                                    message = message.concat("<p>NOT ASSIGNED</p>");
                                } else {
                                    message = message.concat("<a class='linkColor' href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/cnr/viewEditTicket?ticketNumber=" + oData.isAssignedToTicket + "'>" + oData.isAssignedToTicket + "</a>");
                                }
                                message = message.concat("</span>");
                                message = message.concat("</div><div class='col-md-6'></div>");
                            }

                            $(nTd).html(message);
                        }
                    },
                ],

            });

            $('#openConvoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                var sender = $(e.relatedTarget).data('sender');
                var portId = $(e.relatedTarget).data('port');
                console.log(sender + " ---- " +portId);
                $("#conversationsDT").DataTable().ajax.url("getConversation.json?&sender=" + sender + "&portId=" + portId);
                $('#conversationsDT').DataTable().ajax.reload();

                var scrollBody = $(conversationsDT.table().node()).parent();
                scrollBody.scrollTop(scrollBody.get(0).scrollHeight);



            });
```

So when the user clicks on the button to open the modal, the datatable will be generated. The data of the datatable is messages from a certain number, so basically it's a conversation, that's why I need to start from the bottom of the scroll.

If you guys need any other source code just let me know.

Comment: The variable `conversationsDT` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere. Did you mean `$("#conversationsDT")` ?

Comment: ohh I didn't see that I think it should be conversationData, wait I'll try

Comment: @JensV It's still not working, It doesn't have an error anymore, See above code for my changes

Comment: `$('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop($('.dataTables_scrollBody').get(0).scrollHeight)`

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov thanks, but it's still not working :(

Comment: Is there a chance, you're using some legacy version of DataTables or some extensions? If so, you may substitute selector `.dataTables_scrollBody` for something, that will match your scrollable table body (which you may find out easily, using developer console).

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I think that the problem here is that I have 2 datatables. 1 datatable is displayed at the page then the other datatable is displayed when a modal shows

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov But still, I think the other datatable should also be affected if the code is working, since I'm using a class selector.

Comment: Use `:eq()` to affect particular table. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem. See below code

```
"fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
                    var divBodyEl      = oSettings.nScrollBody;
                        if ( (oSettings.bSorted || oSettings.bFiltered) && ! oSettings._drawHold ) {
                                divBodyEl.scrollTop = divBodyEl.scrollHeight;
                        }
                }
```

This code can be found in the **jquery.datatables.js** file. I saw the documentation and they said to place the code in the fnDrawCallback. So yeah it worked!

Thanks for the help!